# Color map to shades of blue - python

Tags: python, plot

I have the following (example) code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl


n_lines = 5
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(x[:, None] + np.pi * np.linspace(0, 1, n_lines))
c = np.arange(1, n_lines + 1)

norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=c.min(), vmax=c.max())
cmap = mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=mpl.cm.jet)
cmap.set_array([])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=100)
for i, yi in enumerate(y.T):
    ax.plot(x, yi, c=cmap.to_rgba(i + 1))
fig.colorbar(cmap, ticks=c)
plt.show();
```

I would like to find a substirute for `cmap.to_rgba` that makes the colour of each line come out as a differnet shade of blue. 
 Basically I want to keep the same layout as the result of this code, but using the colour map `Blues`.

How can I do it?

Comment: use `cmap=mpl.cm.Blues`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to change your colormap that you are using from `jet` to `Blues`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl


n_lines = 5
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(x[:, None] + np.pi * np.linspace(0, 1, n_lines))
c = np.arange(1, n_lines + 1)

norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=c.min(), vmax=c.max())
cmap = mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=mpl.cm.Blues)
cmap.set_array([])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=100)
for i, yi in enumerate(y.T):
   ax.plot(x, yi, c=cmap.to_rgba(i + 1))
fig.colorbar(cmap, ticks=c)
plt.show()
```

This produces:

[image]

Comment: In addiction to @tda answer, you can refer to 'Blues' colormap directly with its key instead of mpl.cm.Blues

Comment: Sure - I was just following OP's style for clarity so he can see where it's coming from :)