# To visualize attention: color tokens using attention weights

Tags: python, matplotlib, deep-learning, visualization, colormap

I have a sequence of tokens and each token has an attention weight. Now, I want to visualize the token using shades of a particular color. For example, shades of blue, from lightest to darkest based on the weights.

I know it is possible to [draw a line or curve that creates shades](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52758070/color-map-to-shades-of-blue-python/52758206). But, how to do that show/print token/word?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. To print in a file, a special file format need to be used. e.g. html
2. Motivated by [this](https://gist.github.com/ihsgnef/f13c35cd46624c8f458a4d23589ac768) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52758070/color-map-to-shades-of-blue-python/52758206?fbclid=IwAR0NsVYYYqG_1KPtU-cbtuU3G-uph3pLOuCIO4GfO0DkMbgvxAl6K-5uClo) the following code will print text with different intensity/shades of blue based on given weights.

   ```
   import numpy as np
   import matplotlib
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

   def colorize(words, color_array):
       cmap=matplotlib.cm.Blues
       template = '<span class="barcode"; style="color: black; background-color: {}">{}</span>'
       colored_string = ''
       for word, color in zip(words, color_array):
           color = matplotlib.colors.rgb2hex(cmap(color)[:3])
           print(color)
           colored_string += template.format(color, '&nbsp' + word + '&nbsp')
       return colored_string

   words = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'.split()
   color_array = np.random.rand(len(words))

   print(color_array)
   s = colorize(words, color_array)

   # or simply save in an html file and open in browser
   with open('colorize.html', 'w') as f:
       f.write(s)
   ```

   Output: 
   [image]